# Scope of function passed to setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm having trouble understanding function scope when called in setInterval.

When I declare an anonymous function directly inside the setInterval like this:

```js
let lastEventUUID = "some ID";
const interval = setInterval(async function() {
  console.log("lastEventUUID -> " + lastEventUUID);
  lastEventUUID = "another ID";
}, 1000);
```

Everything work as expected, I get

```
lastEventUUID -> some ID
lastEventUUID -> another ID
...
```

But when I declare my function separatly

```js
async function myFunc(lastEventUUID) {
  console.log("lastEventUUID -> " + lastEventUUID);
  lastEventUUID = "another ID";
}
```

And call set it in the `setInterval`:

```
let lastEventUUID = "some ID";
const interval = setInterval(myFunc, 1000, lastEventUUID);
```

The `lastEventUUID` is not updated in the next call, I get

```
lastEventUUID -> some ID
lastEventUUID -> some ID
...
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: What is the last parameter you are setting? `setInterval(myFunc, 1000);` is the valid syntax

Comment: You're declaring `async` functions but they're not really `async`. They're plain functions, which is fine because you don't need `async` functions with `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's nothing to do with defining the function separately or not. In your first example, you're using the `lastEventID` variable that the function closes over. In your second example, you're using the `lastEventID` **parameter** that is passed to the function. Since `setInterval` passes it the same one every time, you see the same one every time.

If you do like-for-like, you can define it separately:

```js
async function myFunc() {
  //                  ^----- No parameter declared
  console.log("lastEventUUID -> " + lastEventUUID);
  lastEventUUID = "another ID";
}
let lastEventUUID = "some ID";
const interval = setInterval(myFunc, 1000);
// No argument given to pass to myFunc --^
```

---

Side note: You've defined your function as an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). If your real function is using [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) in the function body, be sure that you have a `try`/`catch` around the **full** body of the function and that you handle any errors; otherwise, an error will result in an "Unhandled rejection" error (since the timer mechanism isn't going to do anything with the promise your function returns, including handling rejections). If your real function doesn't use `await`, there's no reason for it to be `async`.

---

Re your comment:

> From what I understand this work because here lastEventUUID is declared in the global scope, but in my case, it is defined in another function...

No, it doesn't work because it's a global. It works because it's declared in the scope the function is defined in or a parent scope. It works just fine if that's the scope of a function. Example:

```js
function foo() {
  async function myFunc() {
    console.log("lastEventUUID -> " + lastEventUUID);
    lastEventUUID = "another ID";
  }
  let lastEventUUID = "some ID";
  const interval = setInterval(myFunc, 1000);
}
foo();
```

Globals are just an extreme case of this concept, which is called a *closure*. More: [*How do JavaScript closures work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

In fact, if we call that function twice, we see that there is a `lastEventID` variable for *each* of them (which is entirely private to the stuff defined within `foo`):

```js
function foo(x) {
  async function myFunc() {
    console.log("x -> " + x + ", lastEventUUID -> " + lastEventUUID);
    lastEventUUID = "another ID";
  }
  let lastEventUUID = "some ID";
  const interval = setInterval(myFunc, 1000);
}
foo(1);
foo(2);
```

Comment: From what I understand this work because here lastEventUUID is declared in the global scope, but in my case, it is defined in another function like so https://jsfiddle.net/rdnzjt0a/

Comment: @ThéoChampion: No, that's not why it works; I've added to the end of the answer to address that comment with an example.

Answer (score 1):

you can also achieve the same using Closures like this:

```
function myFunc(uuid) {
   return function(){
       console.log("lastEventUUID -> " + uuid);
       uuid = "another ID";
     }
}
let lastEventUUID = "some ID";
const interval = setInterval(myFunc(lastEventUUID), 1000);
```